# Jquery Values undefined

Tags: jquery

My view code snippet is :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
        <p class="lead">
            $21.000
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="section col-xs-12 col-md-12" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
        <h6 class="title-attr"><small>Qty</small></h6>
        <div>
            <div class="btn-minus"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></div>
            <input value="2" class="inputid"/>
            <div class="btn-plus"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12" >
        <a class="btn btn-success small addToCart">Add to cart</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I try to get value of input field using Jquery I am getting undefined. he script snippet is :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.addToCart').click(function() {
        var pos = $(this).parent().find('.inputid').val();
        alert(pos);
    });
});
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here. The alert shows undefined.
Thanks

Comment: try `.parent().prev(".section").find('.inputid')`, problem is that your `parent()` select the div around your `add to cart`, then you search inside that did, and it don't contain `.inputid`

Comment: sorted. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you click on `.addToCart` button, you step up to parent `div` and try find `.inputid` here:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12" >
   <a class="btn btn-success small addToCart">Add to cart</a>
</div>
```

There are no `.inputid` here, that's why `undefined` is in result.

Comment: This isn't an answer. It only explains the problem.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan good explanation of problem already contains solution.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because `.inputid` is a child of a *sibling* to the `parent()` element. To fix this you could traverse the DOM to find the `.row` using `closest()` and then `find()` from there. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.addToCart').click(function() {
    var pos = $(this).closest('.row').find('.inputid').val();
    console.log(pos);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
    <p class="lead">
      $21.000
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="section col-xs-12 col-md-12" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
    <h6 class="title-attr"><small>Qty</small></h6>
    <div>
      <div class="btn-minus"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></div>
      <input value="2" class="inputid" />
      <div class="btn-plus"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
    <a class="btn btn-success small addToCart">Add to cart</a>
  </div>
</div>
```